# Is there any possibility that electron app can be updated by downloading and installing the changes only and not the whole exe file?

Tags: electron, electron-updater

Is there any possibility that electron app can be updated by downloading and installing the changes only and not the whole exe file? As in if I make changes to one file I just wanna update that particular code in the existing exe so that I can reduce the download time.

method to reduce download time or reduce size of exe, or by updating the required code only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Electron (currently) does not provide the ability for **delta** updates.

As you build the "exe" file on your local computer and *publish* it by whatever means / platform, the full "exe" file will always be downloaded and installed by your user, even for minor updates.

That said, a simple Google search has uncovered the below:

- https://electrondelta.com/

  - Associated Repo: https://github.com/electron-delta/electron-delta