How to Reduce Electron.js Executable (.exe) File Size for Subsequent Updates?
The Electron.js executable (.exe) file for my application is larger than desired, especially for frequent updates. Without applying compression techniques, I'm seeking a solution where only new changes are included in updates. I'm also interested in integrating differential updating techniques. Any advice on minimizing update size while maintaining functionality is appreciated.
I haven't implemented any solutions yet. My expectation is to reduce the size of updates by comparing them with previous changes or exploring alternative methods. I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this optimization in an Electron.js application.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds like a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258651/is-there-any-possibility-that-electron-app-can-be-updated-by-downloading-and-ins
